# insert data from a textbox by rst categories

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to insert a value from a textbox to a table record.
I dont want to add a new record 
I want to edit the last record in a table with  rst Categories
 I have this code

```
Private Sub pic16_Click()
Dim rstCategories As Recordset
Set rstCategories = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="my table name", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
With rstCategories
    With rstCategories
    End With

With rstCategories
.MoveLast 0

End With

With rstCategories
    .Edit
    ![field name] = "**read the value of the textbox**"
    .Update
End With
End With
DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acForm, ObjectName:=Me.Name
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="next form", View:=acNormal
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little worried to delve into this, but to answer your question...

```
Private Sub pic16_Click()
CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE tblMyTableName" _
               & " SET Field1=" & Me.TextBox1 _
               & " WHERE QualifyingField1=" & Me.QualifyingControl
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmNextForm"
End Sub
```

`Me.QualifyingControl` being whichever control identifies which record you wish to update, and `QualifyingField1` being the corresponding field.

Comment: the line textbox1 get an error method or members not found. can you be more cleared the _ should be  =

Comment: Yes of course it does - you need to replace Me.TextBox1 with the name of the TextBox control on your form. You cannot just copy and paste this without adding your field and control names in place of the placeholders ;)

Comment: sorry but i need more from you:). Me.QualifyingControl= last record and QualifyingField1 = "reporting name" can you show that in the code

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're asking for isn't actually what you want but...
`& " WHERE [reporting name]=DMax(""[reporting name]"",""tblMyTableName"")"`

Comment: RE: Your first comment edit - The underscores (`_`) is a syntax for continuing a command on the next line. [This link here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/_AtEndOfLine.htm) gives a good short explanation.

Comment: I believe you thought I was quite understands in vca code
The problem i'm not. My database is not written in English
Last request. If you can write all the code with my data
Table name "fault reporting" record name "reporting name" control name "reporting name"